# Can a process running inside a virtual machine get information on processes running outside the virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

Lets say I am running Windows 7 with two major processes I will call V and P.

V is a virtual machine running another instance of Windows 7, while P is the process that I want information about and both are on the 'top-level' operating system.

Can a process, C, which is being run by the Windows 7 inside V, get information about processes such as P from within V? In other words, can a process being run inside a virtual machine get any information about processes being run by the operating system which is also maintaining the virtual machine process? I feel like it would rely on the ability of the virtual machine process, if it is not programmed to specifically retrieve such information then it will not be possible.

I have read another topic about the difficulty of even detecting whether a process is being run by a virtual machine or not. Some feel it is not reliable or possible. I am not sure that there is a standard way to find this out yet, I believe the post was roughly 4 or 5 years ago.

So can this be done by process C, or will there need to be more standard routines to accomplish this task?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Longer answer: "maybe", depending on how many hoops your're willing to jump through the the specific virtualization technology you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible for an operating system running under a virtual machine manager (e.g. (VMWare et al) to directly access information relating to the host operating system because by default most virtual machine managers attempt to fully isolate the host and guest systems.

That being said most virtual machine managers  have mechanisms which allow the virtual machine to share data and communicate with the host system.  By using these mechanisms it is possible for the host operating system to convey information about itself to the guest.

#### Option 1: A shared file

With shared networking between the host and the guest it would be possible to have the host system write the information to a file in the shared location and have the guest open and parse this file using `CreateFile` and a UNC path e.g. `\\host\sharename\file.txt`

#### Option 2: Data transfer via a socket or named pipe

Shared networking between the host and the guest would allow you to use the [Windows Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Named Pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs to create TCP or UDP sockets, or a named pipe through which data can be exchanged.

This approach would involve a server application running on the host application, which writes the process information you're after to the socket or pipe, where it can be read by the guest system which runs a client process.

#### Option 3: Remote Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) Query

WMI provides a standard means of getting information and interacting with many aspects of the windows operating system including information about processes.

This is probably the most complex option because by default WMI does not accept queries from remote hosts (ie. your VM), so the host machine would need to be [configured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to allow remote WMI queries.

Once configured WMI is easily usable via the WMI command line client (`wmic.exe`) so you could invoke it with a query like this:

In this example:

- `%HOST_NAME%` Is the name of the system hosting your Windows 7 VM
- `%TARGET_PROCESS%` is the process name of the process you want
  information about

`wmi \node:%HOST_NAME% process where name='%TargetProcess%' get executablepath`

This particular query gets the executable path of %TargetProcess% but there are many more properties available as per the documentation for the [Win32_Process WMI Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation<sup>1</sup>.

#### Option 4: Shared clipboard

Some virtual machine managers allow the guest system to access the host's clipboard so information can be exchanged between applications running on the guest and host.

I appreciate it's probably the least conventional option but you could conceivably use the [Windows Clipboard API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms648709%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to write the process info to the host's clipboard, and then read the information into a process on the guest system.

<sup>1</sup>**NB:**Although the `Win32_Process` class documentation lists properties in title case (`ExecutablePath`) I found they only worked properly in a `wmic` query when written in all lower case (`executablepath`)

Comment: Is it possible in reverse? Can a host machine know name of  processes running in guest OS running atop VMware workstation / VMware player / VirtualBox

Comment: I'm not sure. It'd depend how much understanding of the guest OS that the hypervisor has. I think in general, these capabilities are more likely to exist via optional extensions added to the guest (VMWare Tools etc), rather than direct interogation by the hypervisor, but I don't have specific evidence to support this.

Comment: Does VMware tools really have capabilities to fetch information (at least names) about processes running on guest OSs?

Comment: Based on some quick googling, it would appear so, at least in the case of the server product line. I'm not sure how much of this applies to the desktop products
https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vcenterhost.doc%2FGUID-F668D27C-28BC-4793-93B9-5842C63F8E25.html